# How can I write or create directories on a shared windows folder in linux?

Tags: windows, linux, share, mount, cifs

After awhile of searching I found the way to mount Windows shared folder on my remote linux server using the steps found [here](http://industriousone.com/blog/mounting-windows-shares-linux). I achieved on getting the file mounted but when i want to write or create a folder it either requires me to sudo in order to write or create a directory.

This is a problem because I'm trying to run a script that downloads files from the internet and automatically creates its files as is needed. I've tried changing the ownership or permission of the shared folder by using commands like `sudo chmod` or `sudo chown` but it tells me that permission was denied and it can't do that.

How can I make it so the shared file I mounted in my linux machine accepts writes or file creation?

Comment: Maybe you should mount it as your user? See the `uid` and `gid` options to cifs filesystem (`man mount.cifs`), IIRC

Comment: That pointed me in the right direction. Apparently that doesn't do the whole trick but helped me to find the correct solution. Since I was needing sudo to make the mount call even after specifying the uid and gid the file wouldn't allow me to write anything. After googling for awhile I found out that theirs a command by -umask=000 that, even though you won't see the permission of writing on the file when you do ls -al, when you enter the folder you mounted it will allow you to write. I think it acts like a sudo or makes your user appear as one, something like that.Either way, it did the trick.

Comment: no, absolutely not. "umask" sets the bitmask of the bits which will be turned off when you create files or directories.

Comment: You can save the uid= and gid= options in /etc/fstab, along with marking the mount point to be mountable by a normal user: `//server/share /net/share cifs user,uid=htj,noauto 0 0`